# Issue Implementing Apigateway using ocelot

Tags: c#, azure, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have asp.net core based microservices project. In this project I am implementing API Gateway using Ocelot nuget package. This project is hosted in linux based docker container in my local development environment.

On testing the microservice url via the api gateway I am getting error 400 not found.

Here goes the configuration file:

```
{
    "ReRoutes": [
        {
            "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/{everything}",
            "DownstreamScheme": "http",
            "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
                {
                    "Host": "authoradmin.command.api",
                    "Port": 80
                }
            ],
            "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/ad/{everything}",
            "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "POST", "PUT", "GET" ]
        }
    ],
    "GlobalConfiguration": {
        "RequestIdKey": null,
        "AdministrationPath": null
    }
}
```

My Docker file is follows:

```
authoradmin.command.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}authoradmincommandapi
    build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: CommandStack/AuthorAdmin.Command.API/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
        - rabbitmq
    links: 
        - rabbitmq
```

Docker override is as follows:

```
authoradmin.command.gateway:
    environment:
        - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
        - IdentityUrl=http://identity.api
    ports:
        - "50106:80"
    volumes:
        -./CommandStack/AuthorAdmin.Command.API:/app/configuration
```

I need to access my apis using apigeteway.

Comment: 400 is a bad request ....

Comment: I apologize when i have tried from postman i am getting could not get any response there was error connecting to.

Comment: Share us the Controller action, request from postman and detail error message. As the comment from LinPy, `400` is bad request instead of not found.